# Is this line of PHP good enough to prevent MySQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code that adds a record to my MySQL database via PHP:
Contact is just a plain string.

```
$contact = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["contact"]), $con); 
$sql="INSERT INTO custom_downloads (contact) VALUES ('$contact')";
```

Is this good enough to prevent any sort of SQL injection attacks? What else can I do to cleanse the data?

Comment: Not "this line" but *these lines*. quotes around $contact variable in the second line is no less important than mysql_real_escape_string in the first one

Comment: too bad you have chosen the worst answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bluebit, your code is secure with regard that you're protecting against SQL Injection but you're not secure against things like **XSS** (Cross Site Scripting). This is the ability to pass **Javascript** into this field and then when you output it, you're outputting the Javascript.

To avoid this you can run your input through **strip_tags() www.php.net/strip_tags** this will remove all HTML tags from your input, thus getting rid of

Here is a nice function that you can reuse for all inputs you're receiveing from $_POST and wish to secure

```
$cleanInput = cleanPost($_POST['contact']);

function cleanPost($item) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($item)));
}
```

There is also a built-in function in PHP for handling input types called **filter_var()** This allows you to specify wether you want to remove HTML and such, just like **strip_tags()**

Hopet this you realise you need to protect against SQL Injection *and* XSS.

Comment: Absolutely. I output the results in a wordpress plugin, so this is quite a scary thought for me. I've added the strip_tags function :)

Comment: If you pass in <script>alert('injected');</script> into your contact field and submit it, see if wordpress is cleverly stripping out tags or not for you. If it's not when you display $_POST['contact'] on your webpage you should receive a javascript alert box.

Comment: Making such a functions is terrible idea. There is no "clean" data format, but totally independent format rules. Too bad this answer been accepted by fellow no-cluer

Comment: all three functions should be used in separate places and for the different data sets. stripslashes on input data at the very beginning of the script. mysql_real_escape_string on the data goes to the query, at the query building time. And strip-tags on the untrusted data only, preferably at output time

Comment: Give the guy a break, he's just looking for an easy way to sanitise input fields for plain text in wordpress.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `mysql_real_escape_string` will correctly escape the string so this is safe from SQL injection.

Comment: You may need the `stripslashes` call if `magic_quotes_gpc` is on...  call it conditionally with `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $var = stripslashes($var); } `

Comment: I'm not sure how stripslashes could cause double escaping (perhaps you were thinking addslahes)? It could however remove any slashes that are supposed to be in the text. The only reason to use stripslashes would be if  you are certain the server the code is running on has magic_quotes enabled.

Comment: OK, yes I was thinking addslashes... not paying attention! I removed the last line.

Comment: you'd better keep it. stripslashes has nothing to do here anyway

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel  7 remarks here but no answer. ( although your info is very helpful ) whats the correct solution according to you?

Comment: @Grumpy answer to what question? A stripslashes one? Get rid of all magiq quotes at the very beginning of the script. See also my comment th the accepted question

Answer (score 3):

You can *never* be sure that `contact` will be a plain string -- it comes from "out there", which automatically makes it unsafe. You should never trust unsafe input, thus parameterized query is the only way to go.

See [this article](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html). Granted, it covers an uncommon situation, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. It's good to always be paranoid about security, but is there actually a problem here? Can you give a specific example of an input that will give problems? I'm curious, because lots of people use this method to escape strings, and if it doesn't work that's a huge problem for a lot of people.

Comment: So what if it's not a plain string? Got an example?

Comment: AFAIK, mysql_set_charset() function, if used instead of SET NAMES query, does solve that problem

Comment: @Col I'm not a PHP expert by any means - I just feel wary about all these string manipulations `mysql_real_escape_string` performs. The `_real_` part bothers me most of all: it's very likely that someday we might have `_really_real_` option.

Comment: That's an old article.  It was a bug back in 2006, and was fixed in 2006...  So no, in any recent version of MySQL (it was fixed in 5.0.22), this is not an issue...

Answer (score 1):

It will not protect you from javascript ; if this string is javascript, and you later display it on a web page, it could be executed.

To be protected from that, you could use `htmlentities`.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but... why bring up Javascript here? It looks like PHP server side code, and seems to have nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: It was just a way to warn him, as he gets his data from an HTML form. If he wants to display it from database on a webpage later, there's a security issue.

Comment: The question was about SQL injection not XSS which is quite another story. (not a downvoter either ;) )

Comment: htmlentities is dead. use htmlspecialchars